Issue installing canvas dependencies on mac m1
I have followed this guide and did:
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg

on a Mac M1 and got stuck on this issue when I ran npm install in the project. Any idea how I can update gobject to the proper version?
Package 'pango' requires 'gobject-2.0 >= 2.62' but version of gobject-2.0 is 2.12.7


Maybe it will not work for everyone, but in my case I figured it out with these commands:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig
  brew install glib
  brew link glib 

if command brew link glib not working use
brew link --overwrite glib
